# Regression equation

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

I'm looking at page 2 in Bollen's (1989) structural equation modeling book. In it, he argues that in a simple regression, the variance of y can be expressed as (b1^2*VAR[x]) + VAR(disturbance). I'm not sure I understand this. I tried this with 10 fake cases of X and Y, but couldn't get it to work. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

Structural equation modelling is a technique for modelling the covariance structure of data, and because of that we can rely on a few rules of covariance algebra. I won't show the proof/derivation of these here, but you can easily find them elsewhere online:

```
 1. var(y) = cov(y, y) 
 2. cov(x, a) = 0, where a is a constant 
 3. cov(x+w, y+z) = cov(x, y) + cov(x, z) + cov(w, y) + cov(w, z) 
 4. cov(ax, by) = ab*cov(x, y)
```

We also know the form of a regression equation is:

```
y = bx + e
```

For your question, you want to express `var(y)` in terms of variances...

Using rule #1:

```
var(y) = cov(y, y)
```

But we also know that `y = bx + e`, therefore:

```
var(y) = cov(bx + e, bx + e)
```

We can rewrite the RHS using rule #3:

```
var(y) = cov(bx, bx) + cov(bx, e) + cov(bx, e) + cov(e, e)
```

Using both rules #1 (for the last term) and 4 (for the first term):

```
var(y) = bb*cov(x, x) + cov(bx, e) + cov(bx, e) + var(e)
```

Because of rule #2, where `e` is a constant, the middle terms drop out. And because `bb` is just `b^2`:

```
var(y) = (b^2)*cov(x, x) + var(e)
```

Finally, `cov(x, x)` is just `var(x)` because of rule #1, and you get what is in your book:

```
var(y) = (b^2)*var(x) + var(e)
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you!